# Restoring database not working

Tags: sql-server

I am using SSMS to restore a specific database. Click on  ...>Tasks>Restore>Database, SSMS doesn't response and doesn't give any message. The issue only happens to one specific database. I tried another database, it worked just fine. Anyone knows why and please help. Thanks.

Comment: Some further info would be helpful: how big is the database you are restoring? Are you restoring on top of an existing database (that might have open connections)? At what point exactly does the problem occur, while you are working through the wizard, or after you hit go?

Comment: What errors did you get? Did you check "kill open conenctions " box

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thank you for your participation. You would help the community immensely if you could supply additional information regarding your issue. E.g. How old is the database? What version of SQL Server are you using? What version of SQL Server Management Studio are you using? How big is the database. Currently your question doesn't contain enough information and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this behaviour when using a system that had never had it's backup history cleared out. It would eventually pop up with the with restore window but took ages.

By default SQL Server will keep a log of all backup history for each database on your system. If you have any maintenance plans that regularly back up databases and clear out backup files as per your retention period you'll have generated a large amount of backup meta-data.

You can see how much has been recorded with this query:

```
select * from msdb.dbo.backupset where database_name = 'YOUR_DBNAME'
```

If it goes back a long way clear out the ancient records with this stored procedure:

```
USE msdb;
GO
EXEC sp_delete_backuphistory @oldest_date = '01/01/2013';
```

If you still get slow performance after clearing it out you may also need to add indexes to the backup table that holds the information.

This [page](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-perform-sql-backup-and-restore-history-cleanup/) covers the index creation and other history clean up tasks in more detail.

Once you're happy with performance you can go back to your maintenance plan and add a task to clear out legacy backup info as part of your backup routine.